# Regex for select multiple names and avoid single name

Tags: c#, regex

I have case. I want to select multiple passenger names from the input. In this case,Condition is that when input contains only single passenger name then avoid this input string.

I create regular expression for this case. It's work for select multiple names from the input but It's not work, when I want to avoid single passenger name in the input.

My aim is that, I want to select only those case who contain multiple passenger names not the single passenger name.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.[a-zA-Z]\S(.+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(item))
            {
                name = m.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us some examples of your input?

Comment: I guess it is `1.Passenger One, Some information,2.Pessange Two, Some other information,...`. Is it?

Comment: @Maloric..I am pasting one link. It's contain two input string. one string contain multiple names and another one contain one name only.http://pastebin.com/9DLhxzUp

Comment: @BilalMirza..Please see Pastebin.com link. I pasted in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex it will help you

(2.[A-z]\S(.+))

Answer (score 1):

FYI, my RegEx is probably not the most optimized, still in the learning.

From the "example" which is:

```
1.ALVARADO/RITA(ADT)   2.CABELLO/LUIS CARLOS STEVE(ADT)
```

To pull at least one name, I used the below RegEx:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\w+/\w+(( \w+)+)?\(\w+\))");
```

To pull more than one name (which is two or more), I used the below RegEx:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\w+/\w+ \w+(( \w+)+)?\(\w+\))");
```

Then, to retrieve the first and last names, I did some string manipulation:

```
// Example string
string item = @"1.ALVARADO/RITA(ADT)   2.CABELLO/LUIS CARLOS STEVE(ADT)";
// Create a StringBuilder for output
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Create a List for holding names (first and last)
List<string> people = new List<string>();
// Regex expression for matching at least two people
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.\w+/\w+ \w+(( \w+)+)?\(\w+\))");
// Iterate through matches
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(item)) {
    //Store the match
    string match = m.ToString();
    // Remove the number bullet
    match = match.Substring(2);
    // Store location of slash, used for splitting last name and rest of string
    int slashLocation = match.IndexOf('/');
    // Retrieve the last name
    string lastName = match.Substring(0, slashLocation);
    // Retrieve all first names
    List<string> firstNames = match.Substring(slashLocation + 1, match.IndexOf('(') - slashLocation -1).Split(' ').ToList();
    // Push first names to List of people
    firstNames.ForEach(a => people.Add(a + " " + lastName));
}

// Push list of people into a StringBuilder for output
people.ForEach(a => sb.AppendLine(a));
// Display people in a MessageBox
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```